# Ширина отдельных элементов jquery

Tags: jquery

Есть некоторое количество span.
Хочу узнать ширину каждого из них, и дать им отрицательный правый маржин с размером в ширину.

Пример [тут](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZoLWZo)

```
$('.multi-link span').each(function(){
      var w = $(this).width;
      console.log(w);
      $(this).css({
        'margin-right': w*(-1)
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(...).width()` -  это функция.

```
var w = $(this).width();
```

Comment: Понял свою ошибку. Спасибо!